# How can I search the button I made in ListView with Search Bar?

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, search, widget

I created a button shape called 'VocabularyWordsButton' and when I try it under a ListView it works just fine. But when I make 100 buttons under ListView, I want to find them via Search Bar. But I don't know how to do it somehow.

What I want to do: I want to distinguish the buttons by filtering the word 'englishWord' among the buttons listed below. When I enter the word in 'englishWord' in Search Bar, I want the buttons containing that word to be filtered.

If I do something like below, only the texts inside are listed, not the button I made.

**VocabularyWordsButton.dart**

```
import 'package:being_moroccan/AdHelper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

class VocabularyWordsButton extends StatefulWidget {
  VocabularyWordsButton(
      {required this.englishWord,
      required this.trasncribedWord,
      required this.arabicWord,
      required this.sound});

  final String englishWord;
  final String trasncribedWord;
  final String arabicWord;
  final String sound;

  @override
  _VocabularyWordsButtonState createState() => _VocabularyWordsButtonState();
}

class _VocabularyWordsButtonState extends State<VocabularyWordsButton> {
  AdHelper adHelper = AdHelper();

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    // TODO: implement didChangeDependencies
    super.didChangeDependencies();

    adHelper.myLargeBanner.load();
  }

  bool _canShowButton = true;

  void hideWidget() {
    setState(() {
      _canShowButton = !_canShowButton;
    });
  }

  final AudioCache _audioCache = AudioCache(
    prefix: 'audio/',
    fixedPlayer: AudioPlayer()..setReleaseMode(ReleaseMode.STOP),
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: !_canShowButton
          ? Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 195.h / 6,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                  ),
                  child: Container(
                    height: 100,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius:
                                  BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
                          child: Center(
                            child: TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                hideWidget();
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    widget.englishWord,
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 30.sp / 2,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                Colors.transparent),
                            shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius:
                                    BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            print('cal');
                            _audioCache.play('${widget.sound}.mp3');
                          },
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        'TRANSCRIBED'.tr(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 25.sp / 2,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                                2,
                                        height: 60.h / 7,
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            widget.trasncribedWord,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 25.sp / 2,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        'ARABIC'.tr(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 25.sp / 2,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Container(
                                        width:
                                            MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                                                2,
                                        height: 60.h / 7,
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            widget.arabicWord,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 25.sp / 2,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  child: AdWidget(ad: adHelper.myLargeBanner),
                ),
              ],
            )
          : Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.1),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20))),
              child: Center(
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    backgroundColor:
                        MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.transparent),
                    shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                      RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20)),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    hideWidget();
                  },
                  child: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Center(
                      child: Text(
                        widget.englishWord,
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 30.sp / 2, color: Colors.white),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

**DictionaryScreen.dart**

```
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:easy_localization/easy_localization.dart';

import 'VocabularyWords/VocabularyWordsButton.dart';

class DictionaryScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'Dictionary_Screen';

  const DictionaryScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DictionaryScreenState createState() => _DictionaryScreenState();
}

class _DictionaryScreenState extends State<DictionaryScreen> {
  TextEditingController editingController = TextEditingController();

  // final duplicateItems = List<String>.generate(10000, (i) => "Item $i");
  // var items = List<String>();

  List<VocabularyWordsButton> words = [
    VocabularyWordsButton(
      englishWord: 'To pray'.tr(),
      trasncribedWord: 'Sella',
      arabicWord: 'صْلّى',
      sound: 'Sella',
    ),
    VocabularyWordsButton(
      englishWord: 'To prefer'.tr(),
      trasncribedWord: 'Feddel',
      arabicWord: 'فْضّلْ',
      sound: 'Feddel',
    )
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: Container(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: TextField(
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {});
                },
                controller: editingController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: "Search",
                    hintText: "Search",
                    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(25.0)))),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                  shrinkWrap: true,
                  itemCount: words.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    if (editingController.text.isEmpty) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('${words[index].englishWord} '),
                      );
                    } else if (words[index]
                        .englishWord
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .contains(editingController.text)) {
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text('${words[index].englishWord} '),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Container();
                    }
                  }),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```